# implementing GUI for chat in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, jtextpane

I want to implement chat application in java, and I want it show messages like Viber :
messages that user send with right alignment 
messages that his friend with left alignment 
also I want different style for them.

chat message could contains : text, images, etc.

I use a `JPannel chatP` for chat window with  `chatP.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chatPl, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)` 
for text message I use JTextpane, and I use `setAlignmentX("alignment");` for set alignment! :

```
       `JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
            return new Dimension(message.length()*5, getContentHeight(message.length()*5,message)+10);
        }
        @Override 
        public Dimension  getMaximumSize(){
            return  new Dimension(message.length()*5, getContentHeight(message.length()*5,message)+10);
        }
    }; jtp.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);`
```

for other type of message I create a JPannel which contains it.
and add these Component to `JPannel chatP`

my problem is to set the size of JTextpane to fix to its message. and also the alignment!

Answer (score 0):

```
jtp.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

is futile. You have to set alignment on Document level. As you said you use styles so yout pane has instance of StyledDocument and you can obtain the document via jtp.getDocument().

The StyledDocument has the method

```
public void setParagraphAttributes(int offset, 
                                   int length, 
                                   AttributeSet s, 
                                   boolean replace);
```

In the AttributeSet  you can set desired alignment and pass to the method applying to desired text fragment to align it.

See [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.JTextPane) example 2 for the center alignment

Comment: how can I set preferedaize for textpane, to fix to its content?

Comment: Then accept the answer as correct. For content size use http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

Comment: I use that, but it didn't estimate height correctly, also I need to measure both height and width, (the text won't change after creating textPane)

Comment: You can't estimate both height and widht. Imagine a big paragraph of text. If you ask it for widht it will be 10 000 and height is 14 pixels (for some font). If the available width is e.g. 800 pixels the text is wrapped into multiple lines and height will be e.g. 100 pixels but if the widht is smaller height is bigger. In fact you should either specify widht and get height for this widht or just call getPreferredSize() and the width will be max widht of line

Comment: I want each of my line be 440px or smaller if the text length is small(so the height should fix for one line and I should estimate width), but I don't know how can I measure the length of text